# PHP: $_SESSION as an array doesn't work, won't let me add new items?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I have a `SELECT` query that retrieves information from a user:

Some personal data and his assigned user roles inside the site, that can be more than one (in the example there are two).

I want to retrieve those user roles and add them to the `$_SESSION` global variable.

This is the query (tested it in phpMyAdmin and it works as intended: retrieves two rows of results because the user is the same but he has two roles ROLE1 and ROLE2):

```
$conectar = mysqli_connect(localhost, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
$consulta = "SELECT usuarios.userID, usuarios.userEmail, usuarios.userPass, usuarios.userFechaGeneracion, usuarios.userNombres, rolesUsuarios.nombreRol
                 FROM rolesUsuarios, usuarios 
                 WHERE usuarios.userEmail='$email'
                 ";
$buscarUsuario = mysqli_query($conectar,$consulta);
        if ($buscarUsuario) { 
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($buscarUsuario);
            [here I have some pass check in place]
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['userNombres'];
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['userID'];
            $_SESSION['nombreRol'] = $row['nombreRol'];
            ....
```

Now, `$_SESSION['nombreRol']` was a string. When I printed it, it only shows ROLE1.

So I tried to convert it to an array an loop through it adding this:

```
$_SESSION['nombreRol'] = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    array_push($_SESSION['nombreRol'], $row['nombreRol']);
}
```

And then killed the session and started again, trying this time to print it as an array with this: `print_r(array_values($_SESSION['nombreRol']));`

And the result shows:

```
Array ( [0] => ROLE1 [1] => ROLE1 [2] => ROLE1 )
```

How should I have all roles in an array in order to use it?

**After Shrikant Mavlankar's comment, I've tried this:**

```
                $rolesAsignados = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($buscarUsuario)){ 
                        array_push($rolesAsignados, $row['nombreRol']);
                    } 

                $_SESSION['nombreRol'] = array();
                for ($i=0; $i < count($rolesAsignados); $i++) { 
                    array_push($_SESSION['nombreRol'], $rolesAsignados[$i]);
                }
```

And then tried to print the session array:

```
print_r(array_values($_SESSION['nombreRol']));
```

It shows:

> Array ( [0] => ROLE2 )

Comment: Because, In your for loop you are pushing same value of $row['nombreRol'] in to session array. I've added my answer below let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Your query does not add up. You're just making a cross select for all the roles for the user. So if you have 10 roles in the roles table, you will get 10 records for all the roles, combined with the user's data. That can't be correct as you will need to create a `JOIN` to select the correct data. Also when a user can have multiple roles, you can't select the user's data AND the roles in one query.

Comment: also I think you want `fetch_assoc` not `fetch_array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no join in your `WHERE`. You're joining one user's record with every row in the roles table, so your result set will be large, but you're only reading the first row.

```
$consulta = "SELECT usuarios.userID, usuarios.userEmail, usuarios.userPass, usuarios.userFechaGeneracion, usuarios.userNombres, GROUP_CONCAT(rolesUsuarios.nombreRol SEPARATOR '|') AS roles
             FROM rolesUsuarios, usuarios 
             WHERE usuarios.userEmail='$email'
                 AND rolesUsarios.userID = usarios.userID
             GROUP BY usarios.userID
             ";
```

Then change your assignment like this:

```
$_SESSION['nombreRol'] = explode('|', $row['roles']);
```

Also, **never put unescaped variables into your SQL statements**. You should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or `mysqli::prepare` to bind variables. There's just no excuse for creating SQL injection flaws nowadays.

Comment: Thanks! Should I put the `$_SESSION['nombreRol']` variable inside the loop? Because if I don't `print_r(array_values($_SESSION['nombreRol']));`  shows just `Array ( [0] => ROLE1 )` . Thanks!
(I've been using `$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);` for the variable)

Comment: It does not need to be inside a loop, just adjacent to the other assignments. Did you add the `AND` from the `WHERE`?

Comment: Thanks!! I've added changes to your answer because usuarios.userNombres returned just the first element, and I needed to grab the CONCAT result field instead.

Comment: Right you are. Feel free to accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I've accepted the answer, it solved the problem!!